# How to extend border to the bottom of page?

Tags: css, html, border

http://jsbin.com/huzem/1/edit?html,css,output

In the above site how do i extend the border to the bottom of the page, compared to where it ends now(right at the edge of the content)?  Also is there a way to make the border line up on the edge of the right and left sides of the screen without using negative values for `margin` such as i did by setting `margin -right` and `margin-left` to `-4%`?

Comment: Which part of the border? ?

Comment: the `border-bottom` property

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width to 93%, and then you are overriding that with your -4% thing - so, just don't do the first part. `body` has a margin of something by default: so get rid of that:

Put a border on your html and body, like - red. and look at what is actually going on. The body only stretches to fit your content... so you need to tell it how big it can be... (100%) then you have to tell the things inside what to do etc... This isn't the complete / perfect answer --- but it should get you closer to your goal.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* remind these guys they can be as tall as the viewport if they want */
}

body{
    margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
    color: white;
    background-color: black; /* white on white is no helpful */
}

#main{
    height: 100%;
}

#content{
    border: solid white; /* you need a px value */
    min-height: 100%;
}

a {
  color:white; /* you don't need to specify for every state */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set the main div at the height of the window and set a height property to 100% to your content div like this :

```
#main {
  width: 93%;
  margin: -2% auto 0% auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#content {
  border: solid white;
  margin: 0% -4% 1000% -4%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The border will now extend to the bottom of the page!